# Why this piece of Python code is taking unusually longer time to compute the sum?

Tags: python, algorithm, code-analysis

I like to explore this in terms of Asymptotic Notations: Big(O), Omega and Theta.

Here is a small piece of Python code. And tried running it by giving larger value each time. If you look at the 3rd scenario(image), the code is taking usually longer time to calculate the sum.

[image]

I wonder if i can rewrite it sequentially, would there be any difference? How can I optimize this code to take larger values? Thank you

Comment: Well, 1e13 is a large number, it's normal the calculation takes a long time. You could take a look at this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). You could return `0.5772156649 + math.log(n)` as an approximation.

Comment: Agreed! How can I optimize my code and make it better to take lesser time to process larger values.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404346/python-program-to-calculate-harmonic-series

Answer (score 0):

You can make the same algorithm a lot faster by using numba:

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def compute(n):
    x = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        x += 1/i
    return x

print(compute(1000000000))
```